# jQuery onclick function working only on first <div>, why?

Tags: jquery, function, onclick

I have html table, and inside the table in each tr line i have the next code :

```
<table>
   <tr><td> <div id="popup_button">Save</div> </td></tr>
   <tr><td> <div id="popup_button">Save</div> </td></tr>
   <tr><td> <div id="popup_button">Save</div> </td></tr>
   <tr><td> <div id="popup_button">Save</div> </td></tr>
</table>
```

and js function is :

```
$("#popup_button").click(function(){
    alert("HELLO");
});
```

The problem is, when i click the #1 line div, its working, BUT when i'm trying to click all the other lines  its not working, and again only the #1 line div in table working ,why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are in wrong way.Instead of same ID must use `class`.Its not a good way.

Answer (score 6):

The id attribute should be unique, if you use a class it will work.

```
 <table>
 <tr><td> <div class="popup_button">Save</div> </td></tr>
 <tr><td> <div class="popup_button">Save</div> </td></tr>
 <tr><td> <div class="popup_button">Save</div> </td></tr>
 <tr><td> <div class="popup_button">Save</div> </td></tr>
 </table>

 $(".popup_button").click(function(){
  alert("HELLO");
 });
```

Answer (score 3):

`id` attribute has to be unique. If you are considering styling in CSS with `#popup_button { }` and for multiple elements use `class`, use a `dot` on this `.popup_button { }` and for `JavaScript` try this:

```
<table>
   <tr><td> <div class="popup_button">Save</div> </td></tr>
   <tr><td> <div class="popup_button">Save</div> </td></tr>
   <tr><td> <div class="popup_button">Save</div> </td></tr>
   <tr><td> <div class="popup_button">Save</div> </td></tr>
</table>


$(".popup_button").click(function(){
    alert("HELLO");
});
```

Answer (score 3):

what is the meaning of ID.

ID should be unique. Use class to manage this type of work.

```
$(".popup_button").click(function(){
     alert("HELLO");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

id must be uniqued,so use class attribute must be work fun:

```
<table>
   <tr><td> <div class="popup_button">Save</div> </td></tr>
   <tr><td> <div class="popup_button">Save</div> </td></tr>
   <tr><td> <div class="popup_button">Save</div> </td></tr>
   <tr><td> <div class="popup_button">Save</div> </td></tr>
</table>
```

js is:

```
$(".popup_button").click(function(){
    alert("HELLO");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your ID attribute should be unique. JQuery is simply selecting the first element with that ID that it finds. If you want to select multiple elements based on a common attribute, supply a `class` attribute. e.g.

```
<div class='popup' />
<div class='popup' />
```

And a JQuery select:

```
$(".popup").click(function() { alert('hello'); });
```

Will do what you want, I think.